# Plesk error when adding a subscription: ODBC error #08S01 can't connect to local MySQL

Tags: centos, mysql, yum, odbc

I'm getting this error after updating MySQL to 5.6 (Plesk 11.5, fresh installation) using the [official MySQL repository](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/) right after adding a new subscription.

```
Internal error: ODBC error #08S01: [unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver]Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Message ODBC error #08S01: [unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver]Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
File     aps_php.php
Line    11933
Type    Exception
```

However database seems to work fine, I can access phpMyAdmin without problems under Settings -> Database Servers. PHP 5.5 using Remi repository.

```
# yum list installed | grep -i mysql
mysql-community-client.x86_64   5.6.17-4.el6                   @mysql56-community
mysql-community-common.x86_64   5.6.17-4.el6                   @mysql56-community
mysql-community-libs.x86_64     5.6.17-4.el6                   @mysql56-community
mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64
                                5.6.17-4.el6                   @mysql56-community
mysql-community-release.noarch  el6-5                          installed
mysql-community-server.x86_64   5.6.17-4.el6                   @mysql56-community
mysql-connector-odbc.x86_64     5.3.2-1.el6                    @mysql-connectors-community
perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64           4.013-3.el6                    @base
php-mysqlnd.x86_64              5.5.11-1.el6.remi              @remi-php55
```

Libraries installed (note: I've manually created the symbolic link `/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so` because was absent):

```
# ls -l /usr/lib64/ | grep -i myodbc
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  4294072 Mar 27 15:41 libmyodbc5a.so
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       25 May  2 14:43 libmyodbc5.so -> /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5w.so
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  4292472 Mar 27 15:41 libmyodbc5w.so
```

Content of `/etc/odbcinst.ini`:

```
[PostgreSQL]
Description = ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver      = /usr/lib/psqlodbc.so
Setup       = /usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64    = /usr/lib64/psqlodbc.so
Setup64     = /usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage   = 1

[MySQL]
Description = MySQL driver for Plesk
Driver      = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup       =
FileUsage   = 1
Driver64    = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64     =
UsageCount  = 1

[MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver]
Driver     = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5w.so
UsageCount = 1

[MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver]
Driver     = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5a.so
UsageCount = 1
```

Any help I much appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. Just discussing yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428301/correct-way-of-updating-php-mysql-on-a-running-plesk-11-5-server:

```
ln -s /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Great. Curious to know what causes the problem.

Comment: As I see it's happens when mysql and odbc connector installed from different sources, so ODBC libs (libmyodbc5) points to old mysql.sock location because this path is compiled within lib binary.

Comment: It is my case. I have Plesk on CentOS 5 but I did an update to MySQL 5.5 form another repo (CentOS 6 repo offered only MySQL 5.1). I remember missing ODBC consequently to update was fixed by Parallels support (so was probably the Plesk repo). But this was months ago. Recently I did a restart and then I noticed the problem. Maybe the restart deleted /temp files. There is a way to make this fix permanent or I should reinstall (and how) MySQL or ODBC from right sources?

Comment: To keep link after server restart add following string in the beginning of /etc/init.d/mysqld:

if [ ! -L /tmp/mysql.sock ]; then  ln -s /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock ; fi

Comment: ok. It is worthless to reinstall?

Comment: Don't think so.